# How to add item details within a in a multi-step wizard process?

Tags: forms, design-patterns, wizard

I am working on a project that involves a wizard-type form workflow. In one part of the process, our system will return items we found for the user. The user will then need to provide details about each item before continuing.

### Approach 1

[image]

**1. List of items screen** - User is shown a (checkbox) list of existing
items (typically <5). The user checks the relevant items they want
to keep and moves on.

**2. Details screen(s)** - For each item selected,
there is a corresponding detail screen to follow. Example: user
selects 2 of 3 items.

- Item 1 details input screen
- Item 2 details input screen

**3. Summary screen** - shows a summary of the 2 items the user chose with a link to edit
details or delete item(s). The user may also manually add another item that was not returned among the initial results before continuing.

### Approach 2

After speaking with the developer, they recommended using checkboxes to navigate to the details screens so the full list of items could always be accessed; a combination of List of items screen + Summary screen.

[image]

**1. Summary screen** - User is shown a (checkbox) list of existing items. The user would check the relevant item(s) they want to keep.

**2. Details screen** - When Item 1 is checked, the user is immediately taken to the Item 1 Details screen to input details.

**3. Summary screen** - Once Item 1 Details screen is complete, the changes are saved, and the user is taken back to the Summary screen. That checked Item 1 now has an edit link visible so the user can return to the Item 1 details screen. The user may also manually add another item that was not returned among the initial results before continuing. (Unchecking the item would discard the details, and hide the edit link)

#### Concerns with Approach 2:

- **Checkbox has multiple functions.** The checkbox serves as both a navigation element and an editing mechanism when checked.
- **Checkboxes are not generally recognized or leveraged as navigational elements.** As a user, I would not expect a checkbox to refresh my view or otherwise transport me anywhere. Not traumatizing, but a little unexpected.
- **Irrelevant content remains on screen.** The developer's primary criticism of Approach 1 was that the user could not add another item from the initial results. However, my position is that a.) the user has made a conscious choice to omit a result by not checking it (winnowing) and b.) they are able to manually add an item from the summary screen.

Comment: How many details will be shown? Are those just sub-items of the main items or explanatory details?

Comment: @jonvyltra It can vary. But an ITEM detail screen will have 5-10 input fields. The input fields represent properties of the respective ITEM.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote:

> Checkboxes are not generally recognized or leveraged as navigational elements. As a user, **I would not expect a checkbox to refresh my view or otherwise transport me anywhere**. Not traumatizing, but a little unexpected.

This is a very good reason to not use Approach 2.

EDIT: What about the checkbox expanding the details needed from the user? In form of an accordion-like layout.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I appreciate the additional input. The accordion(s) aren't a bad plan. The details screen would have 5-10 inputs per item. If you would imagine 2 items x 10 inputs, there could be up to 20 fields visible on the screen. This begins to open up concerns about scroll distance on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I see with your "Approach 1" is that it has 2 different ways of adding and editing items, which can create confusion. And also, if the user selects 4+ items initially, after that, having to go through 4+ edit views is tiresome and disconnected from the initial interaction of picking items.

I think your "Approach 2" is better, but with a few changes:

1. Remove checkboxes completely. Make all items look like buttons.
2. When an item is selected, show a checkmark icon (not checkbox) in a corner and remove the "edit" button. Allow user to click on any item to select or edit.
3. In item view, add "remove" button if the item was selected or "cancel" button if it's a new item. Also use "create" button if the item is new, or "apply" button if the item was already selected and it's being edited.
4. When the user returns from editing a selected item, move that item on top of the list. Keep selected items always on top.
5. On summary view, display only the selected items and only as text, without "edit" buttons. Use instead 2 main buttons ("back" and "finish") so that the user can return to the previous view to edit/create items, or press finish and finalize the process.
6. Summary view should be used only for summary and it should display all the input provided by user for all items and all input fields. This view should be optimized for easy scanning and error detection. See transactions in fintech apps for more inspiration.